# Flex Container Taking Width of Element

Tags: html, css

I'm putting a label and an input inside a div that is a flex container and flex-direction is set to column. The container naturally takes the width of the input and not the label. I'm trying to figure out why that is and if there is a way I can get the container to take the width of the label (or what the width of the label should be)

"Relationship to Patient" is the label/input in question.

### What I want (on my my extra large screen):

[image]

### What I'm getting (on my large screen):

[image]

### HTML (using React and Nextjs):

```
<div className={styles.inputContainer}>
    <label className={styles.label}>Relation to Patient</label>
    <select className="form-field">
        <option>Self</option>
        <option>Child</option>
        <option>Spouse</option>
        <option>Parent</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
:root {
    --primary: #50657a;
    --secondary: #7a5050;
    --tertiary: #797a50;
    --lightGray: #bababa;
    --darkGray: #4d4d4d;
    --extraLightGray: #ededed;
}

.inputContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* width: 200px */
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 .5rem;
}

.label {
    color: var(--secondary);
}

.formRow {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: .5rem 0;
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
}

.form-field {
    border: 1px solid #bababa;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.form-field:focus {
    outline: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(80,101,122,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(80,101,122,.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(80,101,122,.25);
}
```

### Parent element:

```
<div className={styles.formRow} style={{ marginTop: '0' }}>
    /* A bunch of other code */
    <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
        <label className={styles.label}>Relation to Patient</label>
        <select className="form-field">
            <option>Self</option>
            <option>Child</option>
            <option>Spouse</option>
            <option>Parent</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, reminder, I'm trying to figure out why the flex container chooses the width of the input and not the label and also how I can get the desired results.

I very much appreciate any/all help and answers!!

Comment: Hard to say without a runnable demo, but try adding `flex-grow: 1;` to the container you want to grow to take the available space. You may also need your margins set to `auto` rather than defining a pixel value.

Comment: @Slbox any suggestions for best place to put a demo up? Also, the margin being set to auto, for which selector are you referring to?

Comment: @MatthewWolman You can include code snippets by clicking the file icon when editing your post. But Codepen or JSfiddle are also great.

Comment: Great suggestion for a snippets fellas

Comment: Please include an example with the generated HTML (rather than the script) in a Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` button on the question editor toolbar - this will create a runnable snippet directly in the question, which is the preferred way for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe you should try to add a width to the class form-field. Will be waiting on the code snippet.

Comment: Hey guys thank you for the advice on the code snippet. I'll do that next time but I figured this issue out. It was simply a matter of one of the grand parent elements had a fixed width set that was stopping the growth of the element. How should I handle this? Should I delete the question?